# java Scanner splitting strings

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

So Im stuck on a homework assignment, and would only like a little bit of assistance I have 3 text files with multiple student names and their grades in the format:

```
Student Name

Test 1: 93
______________
Student Name

Test 1: 99
_____________

I need to figure out a way to split the line where the grade is and skip the ------- that splits the students and their grades up. I would then need to parse the test grade into a variable so i could do calculations with it. 

     public void openFile() throws IOException {
                //opens text file
                try {
                    FileReader inputFile = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Chris\\IdeaProjects\\workshop3\\src\\filereader\\file1.txt");
                    //delimiter from scanner object skips characters passed as parameters
                    kb = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter("\n");
                    while(kb.hasNext()){
                        line = kb.next();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I am now having a problem with this method, i am using an array list to loop into writing student. But everytime something is written to the specified file it keeps writing over the existing student information in the file. Hopefully someone can help.

```
public void writeFile(Student stud) throws IOException{
        try{
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Chris\\IdeaProjects\\workshop3\\src\\filereader\\file4.txt"));


            outputFile.println("\nStudent: " + stud.getName());
            outputFile.println("Midterm 1: " + stud.getMid1());
            outputFile.println("Midterm 2: " + stud.getMid2());
            outputFile.println("Final: " + stud.getFin());
            outputFile.printf("Average: %.2f"  ,stud.calculateAverage(stud.getMid1(),stud.getMid2(),stud.getFin()));


            outputFile.close();

        }catch(IOException e){

        }
    }
```

Comment: I still cant figure out why this file keeps writing over itself when it is writting to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split function in string class like.

```
String line= "Test:93";
String[] splits = line.split(":") // which would give {"Test","93"}
```

Comment: how would i use the delimiter to solve this problem instead of using a split method

Comment: are you saying that there is a ---------- line after every student and his grade?

Comment: yes pretty much, and i need to get the student name and grade into something i can perform some averages with and then write it to a file.

Comment: Use scanner.nextLine insteat and skip that particular line

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Scanner` it already has method `nextLine()` which uses `\n` as delimiter.

> Student Name
>
> Test 1: 99
>
> I need to figure out a way to split the line where the grade is and
>   skip the ------- that splits the students and their grades up

With reference to you post, you could try this:

```
kb = new Scanner(inputFile);
int grade;
while(kb.hasNextLine()){
    line = kb.nextLine();//read complete line
    if(line.startsWith("----")) {
       continue;//skip it
    }
    if(line.contains(": ")) {
       //student grades
       grade = Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\:\\s")[1]);
    } else {
       //student name
    }
}
```

Here, for grades I wrote this: `Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\:\\s")[1])`. Since as you mentioned grades are separated by `:`, `line.split("\\:\\s")` will give you an String array with values except for delimiter e.g. if input is `Test 1: 99`, it gives `["Test 1", "99"]`. Now you need int value for calculation so I used `Integer.parseInt(String)`.